# $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, prove $x^{\frac85}+y^{\frac85}+z^{\frac85} \geqslant 3$

Tags: inequality

$x,y,z \geqslant 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, prove
$$x^{\frac85}+y^{\frac85}+z^{\frac85} \geqslant 3$$
1) The equality occurs only at $x,y,z=1$. Let's assume $F=x^n+y^n+z^n$, I noticed that $n=1$ then $F \leqslant 3$ and $n=2$ then $F \geqslant 3$. I believe $n=\frac85=1.6$ is a very sharp inequality.
2) I try trig substitution but cannot remove the radical . $n=\frac85$  is too much for algebraic manipulation.

Comment: i expect the critical exponent is $\beta = \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} \approx 1.5849625$

Comment: No, $(2,0,0)...$

Comment: How do you calculate this bifurcation point, Professor Will Jagy ?

Comment: I just arranged $2^\beta = 3.$ My current guess is that the conclusion of the problem is still true when $8/5$ is replaced by $\beta;$ however, the standard technique, Lagrange multipliers, is not so easy in this case, so I cannot be sure yet. However, it does work on the boundary curves, where one of $x,y,z$ is set to $0,$ so that suggests optimism. Suggest you draw the curve $x^\beta + y^\beta = 3$ with $z=0,$ and $x,y \geq 0,$ compare that with the quarter circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4.$

Comment: Thank you Prof. Will Jagy. Your answer for $\beta_{crit}$ is absolutely corrected. I hope to see your formal solution soon.

Comment: You could try the substitution $x=2\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(a+b)(a+c)}}$ and cyclicly for $y$ and $z$. This eliminates the condition and homogenizes the inequality.

Comment: It is a good solution. I enjoys it. Thx Piquito

Comment: @WillJagy I am wrong I did not even read problem properly and ignored $4$.

Comment: @WillJagy I take it back I still do not see error in my post.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=2\cos\alpha$ and $y=2\cos\beta$, where $\{\alpha,\beta\}\subset\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Hence, $z=2\cos\gamma$, where $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$ and $\gamma\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Let $f(x)=\left(\cos x\right)^{\frac{8}{5}}$.

Since $f''(x)=\frac{-8(1+4\cos2x)}{25\sqrt[5]{\cos^2x}}\geq0$ for all $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, by  Vasc's RCF Theorem

it remains to prove our inequality for $\beta=\alpha$ and $\gamma=\pi-2\alpha$ or

for $y=x$ and $z=2-x^2$, where $0\leq x\leq\sqrt2$.

Id est, it remains to prove that $2x^{\frac{8}{5}}+(2-x^2)^{\frac{8}{5}}\geq3$, which is obvious.

Comment: @HN_NH Explain please your down-voting.

Answer (score 2):

Remark: I give two proofs.

**Proof 1**

Let $x = \sqrt{a}, y = \sqrt{b}, z = \sqrt{c}$. The condition becomes
$a, b, c\ge 0$ with $a + b + c + \sqrt{abc} = 4$. We need to prove that $a^{4/5} + b^{4/5} + c^{4/5} \ge 3$.

We split into two cases:

1) $abc = 0$: WLOG, assume $c=0$. It suffices to prove that $(4-b)^{4/5} + b^{4/5} \ge 3$ for $b\in [0, 4]$.
Let $f(b) = (4-b)^{4/5} + b^{4/5}$. Clearly, $f(b)$ is concave on $[0, 4]$. Also, $f(0) = f(4) = 4^{4/5} > 3$.
Thus, $f(b) > 3$ for $b\in [0, 4]$.

2) $abc > 0$: From Vasc's Equal Variable Theorem [1, Corollary 1.9, Case 1 (b)], 
there exists $a_1=b_1\ge 0, c_1\ge 0$ such that $a_1+b_1+c_1 = a+b+c$, $a_1b_1c_1=abc$,
and $a_1^{4/5}+b_1^{4/5} + c_1^{4/5} \le a^{4/5} + b^{4/5} + c^{4/5}$. Thus, we only need to prove the case
when $a=b$. From $a, c > 0$ and $2a+c + a\sqrt{c} = 4$, we have $a\in (0, 2)$ and $c = (2-a)^2$.
We need to prove that $2a^{4/5} + (2-a)^{8/5} \ge 3$ for $a\in (0, 2)$.

Let $x = a^{4/5}$. It suffices to prove that $2x + (2-x^{5/4})^{8/5} \ge 3$ for $x \in (0, 2^{4/5})$.
Let $g(x) = 2x + (2-x^{5/4})^{8/5}$. We have $g'(x) = 2 - 2(2-x^{5/4})^{3/5}x^{1/4}$
and $g''(x) = (2x^{5/4}-1)(2-x^{5/4})^{-2/5}x^{-3/4}$.
Thus, $g''(x) \le 0$ for $x\in (0, 2^{-4/5}]$ and $g''(x) > 0$ for $x\in (2^{-4/5}, 2^{4/5})$.
Thus, $g(x)$ is concave on $(0, 2^{-4/5}]$, and $g(x)$ is convex on $(2^{-4/5}, 2^{4/5})$.
Since $g(0) > 3$ and $g(2^{-4/5}) > 3$, we have $g(x) > 3$ on $(0, 2^{-4/5}]$.
Since $g'(1) = 0$, we have $g(x) \ge g(1) = 3$ on $(2^{-4/5}, 2^{4/5})$.
Thus, $g(x) \ge 3$ on $(0, 2^{4/5})$.

We are done.

*Reference*

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, “The Equal Variable Method”, J. Inequal. Pure and Appl. Math., 8(1), 2007.
https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf

$\phantom{2}$

**Proof 2**

We will use the following bound (the proof is not hard and thus omitted):
$$u^{8/5} \ge \frac{3}{20}u^4 - \frac{7}{10}u^3 + \frac{31}{20}u^2, \quad u \in [0, 2].$$

With the bounds above, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{3}{20}(x^4+y^4+z^4) - \frac{7}{10}(x^3+y^3+z^3) + \frac{31}{20}(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge 3.$$

We may prove it by using e.g. pqr method, though it is ugly.
I omitted the proof here. I hope to see nice proofs.